# Upvoting an answer while I can't accept still results in "Accept the answer" popup

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, up-votes, popups

I saw something recently, and I found it quite annoying :P.

I asked a question, and chose to upvote an answer that I recieved about 5 minutes after I posted the question

However, after clicking the button, I got a popup saying something like this: `Accept the answer if you found it helpful`. This is not exactly what it said, but it is similar.

But then I realised that I could not accept the answer, as I must accept after 20 minutes.

My point is that the Popup shows saying accept, when I can't accept it, and is this a bug or bad feature design, and I think it should be changed to show the popup only if you **actually can** accept that answer.

Thanks.

Comment: On the other hand: if the message would be suppressed, then *when* could the system explain to upvote-happy new users how things work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem.

The message says

> Don't forget you can mark this as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark

It's not saying you can mark this as the accepted answer *now*. It's just saying, don't forget that you *can*. As Arjan said, if we don't remind users, they might forget.

Now, *maybe* the popup should say:

> Don't forget you can mark this as the accepted answer in 14 minutes by clicking the checkmark

But, is that really necessary? You knew as soon as you clicked the checkmark that you had to wait 14 minutes.